# Adding time to a date in Python

Tags: python, datetime

I would like to add time to a date. Date and time are strings

```
12/28/2018 23:30:00
```

now in this i would like to add Time

```
02:30:00
```

in output:

```
12/29/2018 02:30
```

I've tried the following:

```
import datetime
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

departure_time = "15:30"
duration = "00:00:50"

#I convert the strings to datetime obj
departure_time_obj = datetime.strptime(departure_time_obj, '%H:%M')
duration_obj = datetime.strptime(duration_obj, '%H:%M:%S')

arrival_time = dtt + datetime.timedelta(duration_obj)
print(arrival_time)
```

I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: type object 'datetime.datetime' has no attribute 'timedelta'
```

Comment: Your import is wrong. Since you're importing Timedelta directly using "from ... import ..." You don't need to write `datetime.timedelta` but instead just `timedelta`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `timedelta(hours=duration_obj.hour, minutes=duration_obj.minute, seconds=duration_obj.second)`

**Ex:**

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

departure_time = "15:30"
duration = "00:00:50"

#I convert the strings to datetime obj
departure_time_obj = datetime.strptime(departure_time, '%H:%M')
duration_obj = datetime.strptime(duration, '%H:%M:%S')

arrival_time = departure_time_obj + timedelta(hours=duration_obj.hour, minutes=duration_obj.minute, seconds=duration_obj.second)
print(arrival_time)
```

**Note:** You have already imported `timedelta`